# Small Json web service SQL issue

Tags: php, json

I have a web service that reads in two variables and searches on either one or the other, or both. If the two variables are empty, then I want to select all of the data - something that isn't currently working. Here is the web service:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");

    try {
        $conn       =       new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=treeves;", "treeves", "oopheiye");
        $region     =       $_GET["region"];
        $type       =       $_GET["type"];

        if(empty($region)) {
            $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest WHERE type LIKE '$type'");
        }
        elseif(empty($type)) {
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest WHERE region LIKE '$region'");
        }
        elseif (!empty($region) && !empty($type)){
        $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest WHERE type='$type' AND region LIKE '$region'");
        }
        else  {
        $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM pointsofinterest");
        }
                $array  =   array();

                while ($row = $result->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    $array[] = $row; 
                }
                echo json_encode($array);
                    if($array === false || is_null($array)) {
                        throw new Exception('Could not encode JSON');
                        }
        } catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

It works fine, and searches on one or the other or both of the variables, but it returns [] in the response if a parameter isn't passed through.

Thanks.

Comment: you are not using `PDO` properly!!!! you are open to SQL injections!!!

Comment: I know - this will get amended

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the conditions to be able to handle the default case. You'll need to change it to

```
if (empty($region) && !empty($type)) { /*...*/ }
elseif(!empty($region) && empty($type)) { /*...*/ }
elseif(!empty($region) && !empty($type)) { /*...*/ }
else { /*...*/ }
```

Otherwise, when you don't supply a parameter you'll always hit the first branch.